# how to access my code from intents in siri ios10

Tags: ios, xcode, sirikit

I have implemented [siri extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/) to my app messages (siri kit iOS10) as shown in apple sample code

1. I implemented  siri extension class to get number and message body from siri voice
2. this two parameters passing to my app source code
3. here Xcode showing linker command error 
   i didn't understand what i am missing in this code

When add this code to extension class it showing

> error:`[[UCSMSHandleManager sharedinstance] sendTextMessage:digits withMsg:message];`

[image]